# What is the difference between JpaRepository and MongoRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I don't know the difference between `JpaRepository` and `MongoRepository`.

Comment: JPA is the Java Persistence API, against which you can write your own repositories.  MongoRepository is apparently one such repository that is specific to MongoDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JPARepository and MongoRepository are technology-specific abstraction of the Spring Data Repositories.

If you are using RDBMS such as MySQL/PostgreSQL, you may use Spring Data Repositories such as JpaRepository. 
If using a NoSQL such as Mongo, you will need the MongoReposiroty.